# How to mass assign all attributes of a Backbone model?

Tags: backbone.js, model, attributes

I would like to update the `User` model whenever `signIn` was **successful**. It includes the `id` assign by the backend which has not been present in the model before.

```
MyApp.module("User", function(User, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

  User.Controller = Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({

    initialize: function() {
      this.model = new MyApp.User.Model();
    },

    signIn: function(credentials) {
      var signInData = { user: credentials };
      var self = this;

      App.session.signIn(signInData, {
        success: function(model, response, options) {
          self.updateUserModel(model);
        },
        error: function(model, xhr, options) {}
      });
    },

    updateUserModel: function(model) {
      // TODO Update all attributes, including new onces e.g. id.
    }

  });
});
```

How would you update all attribtues at once? I know that I manually can [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) every single attribute but this seems to be wrong since the list of attributes may change over time.
Generally, I would expect such an `update(model)` method in the `User` model.

---

When I use Backbone's `model.set()` method as suggested by *nikoshr* and *john-4d5* ...

```
    signIn: function(credentials) {
      var signInData = { user: credentials };
      var self = this;

      App.session.signIn(signInData, {
        success: function(model, response, options) {
          self.model.set(model);
        },
        error: function(model, xhr, options) {}
      });
    },
```

... the `id` attribute is copied into `this.model` but other properties such as `name` are missing.

The model returned in the `success` callback looks like this:

```
_changing: false
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
    bind: function (name, callback, context) {
    close: function (){
    constructor: function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
    created_at: "2013-07-22T19:03:24Z"
    email: "user@example.com"
    id: 3
    initialize: function () {
    listenTo: function (obj, name, callback) {
    listenToOnce: function (obj, name, callback) {
    logout: function () {
    model: child
    name: "Some User"
    off: function (name, callback, context) {
    on: function (name, callback, context) {
    once: function (name, callback, context) {
    options: Object
    signIn: function (credentials) {
    signUp: function (credentials) {
    stopListening: function (obj, name, callback) {
    trigger: function (name) {
    triggerMethod: function (event) {
    unbind: function (name, callback, context) {
    updated_at: "2013-08-05T13:20:43Z"
    user: Object
    __proto__: Object
    changed: Object
cid: "c3"
id: 3
__proto__: Surrogate
```

Comment: I might have missed something, but what's wrong with `this.model.set(model);` ?

Comment: @nikoshr Actually I did not see this in the documentation. I tried it but it does not copy other attributes then `id`. For instance `name` is missing on the updated model.

Comment: So, what does `model` contain (the first parameter in your success callback)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- You are moving around a `Backbone.Model`,
- [`Model.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) accepts a hash of attributes,
- you can convert a `Backbone.Model` to a hash of attributes with [`Model.toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON)

You could write your callback as

```
success: function(model, response, options) {
    self.model.set(model.toJSON());
}
```

Comment: I found an alternative which works: `self.model.set(model.attributes)`. This seems to be ment for what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Does your comment mean you would discourage from using `.attributes`?

Comment: It's meant to be an internal representation. It would probably work in your case, but there's no guarantee that it stays as it is in future versions of Backbone. I tend to be cautious and would favor `Model.toJSON`

Comment: I actually cannot read this from the docs. In the opposite `.toJSON()` appears more unsteady to me, such as `.toString()`.

Comment: I believe there were architectural mistakes in how I handled the models (user, session). I changed the setup now. I will accept your answer since it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `set`, giving the other model's `attributes` property value (an object with all the attribute values) as an argument.

`self.model.set(model.attributes);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.model.set(model)` as @nikoshr said. Iterate over the attributes and setting each one will do the same thing as model.set already does. Refer to the backbone's `model.set` function:

```
// Set a hash of model attributes on the object, firing `"change"`. This is
// the core primitive operation of a model, updating the data and notifying
// anyone who needs to know about the change in state. The heart of the beast.
set: function(key, val, options) {
  var attr, attrs, unset, changes, silent, changing, prev, current;
  if (key == null) return this;

  // Handle both `"key", value` and `{key: value}` -style arguments.
  if (typeof key === 'object') {
    attrs = key;
    options = val;
  } else {
    (attrs = {})[key] = val;
  }

  [...]

  // For each `set` attribute, update or delete the current value.
  for (attr in attrs) {
    val = attrs[attr];
    if (!_.isEqual(current[attr], val)) changes.push(attr);
    if (!_.isEqual(prev[attr], val)) {
      this.changed[attr] = val;
    } else {
      delete this.changed[attr];
    }
    unset ? delete current[attr] : current[attr] = val;
  }
 [...]
}
```

Another option is to instantiate a new model:

```
this.model = new MyApp.User.Model(model);
```